# How to use a JSON value as a Date

Tags: scala, slick

I have an application that connects with a PostgreSQL using Slick.

As the model uses a JSON column that contains a date, I am trying to figure out how to filter by that date.

This is a similar DB definition:

```
class EventsDAO(tag: Tag) extends Table[Event](tag, "events") {
  def info = column[JsValue]("info")
  ...
}

case class Event(info: JsValue)
```

This is the query I would like to translate to Slick:

```
SELECT *
FROM events
WHERE Date(f.home_description ->> 'creationDate') < Date('2015-09-28')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you use Postgres native date type directly?

If it's an existing database that cannot be changed, you can either

1. do the filter in your application layer (this should work fine for small dataset)
2. use plain sql query from slick [plain-sql](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.0.0/sql.html)
3. you can write a mapping function to convert the JSON into Date type, check [User defined feature](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.0.0/userdefined.html#scalar-database-functions)

Have a look on [slick-pg](https://github.com/tminglei/slick-pg) if you haven't, it provides support for JSON and Date type.

Comment: I was using plain-sql, but I decided to write a mapping function. Thanks